# Extracting digit from character string and transforming it to a number

Tags: r, string, dataformat

Let's say I have a data frame with vectors A:E where vector E looks like this:

```
ABCDEF50GH
ABCDEF600GH
ABCDEF50GH
ABCDEF1000GH
```

---

Part of my code looks like this:

```
DF <- (filter(DF1, A == "AH") %>%
         mutate(B = nchar(E),
                C = case_when(D == "X" ~ "0",
                              B == 10 ~ substr(E, 7, 8),
                              B == 11 ~ substr(E, 7, 9),
                              B == 12 ~ substr(E, 7, 10),
                              TRUE ~ "0")))
```

So I try to extract a number from a string.
The problem is, extracted number is a character not a number so i need to make other arguments of case_when as characters too.
Therefore vector C is a character vector and when I try to transform it to numeric:

```
transform(DF, C = as.numeric(levels(C))[C])
```

I get a vector with NAs instead of numbers.

Pls help

Comment: why not `stringr::str_extract(DF1$E, "[0-9]+")` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `stringr` to extract digits and then simply transform the outcome to a numeric vector:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

sample.df <- data.frame(E = c(
  "ABCDEF50GH",
  "ABCDEF600GH",
  "ABCDEF50GH",
  "ABCDEF1000GH"
), 
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

sample.df <- sample.df %>%
  mutate(E_numbers = str_extract_all(E, "[[:digit:]]+")) %>%
  mutate(E_numbers = unlist(E_numbers)) %>% 
  mutate(E_numbers = as.numeric(E_numbers))

> sample.df
             E E_numbers
1   ABCDEF50GH        50
2  ABCDEF600GH       600
3   ABCDEF50GH        50
4 ABCDEF1000GH      1000
```

`str_extract_all()` returns a list which can be tricky to handle, therefore I use `unlist()` other than that, it should be straightforward :)

Note: the difference between `str_extract_all()` and `str_extract()` is that `str_extract()` will only catch the first number in your strings. So if one of the strings in `E` was `"ABCDEF600G400H"`, `str_extract_all()` would return the numbers `600` and `400` while `str_extract()` would return `600`. Not sure what is preferable in your case.

Edit: If you want to extract only the last number in `"ABCDEF600G400H"` we can use the `stringi` package instead of `stringr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)

sample.df <- data.frame(
  E = c(
    "ABCDEF50GH",
    "ABCDEF600GH",
    "ABCDEF50GH",
    "ABCDEF1000GH",
    "ABCDEF600G400H"
  ), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

sample.df <- sample.df %>%
  mutate(E_numbers = stri_extract_last_regex(E, "[[:digit:]]+")) %>%
  mutate(E_numbers = unlist(E_numbers)) %>% 
  mutate(E_numbers = as.numeric(E_numbers))
> sample.df
               E E_numbers
1     ABCDEF50GH        50
2    ABCDEF600GH       600
3     ABCDEF50GH        50
4   ABCDEF1000GH      1000
5 ABCDEF600G400H       400
```

Comment: what if i want to extract 400 from "ABCDEF600G400H" ? any other way than substr(E, 9,B) and then following your previous answer?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using stringr package

```
text <- as.data.frame(c("ABCDEF50GH",
    "ABCDEF600GH",
              "ABCDEF50GH",
              "ABCDEF1000GH"))
colnames(text)<-c("names")

library(stringr )
text$numerics <-  str_extract(text$names,  "[[:digit:]]+")
```

if you want to convert it to numeric just add as.numeric

```
text$numerics <-  as.numeric(str_extract(text$names,  "[[:digit:]]+"))
```

Answer (score 0):

data: borrowed from JBGruber

```
sample.df <- data.frame(
    E = c(
        "ABCDEF50GH",
        "ABCDEF600GH",
        "ABCDEF50GH",
        "ABCDEF1000GH",
        "ABCDEF600G400H"
    ), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

base solution to extract the last number:

```
m <- gregexpr("\\d+(?=\\D+$)",text = sample.df$E, perl = T)
sample.df$E_numbers <- as.numeric(regmatches(sample.df$E, m))
```

result:

```
#               E E_numbers
#1     ABCDEF50GH        50
#2    ABCDEF600GH       600
#3     ABCDEF50GH        50
#4   ABCDEF1000GH      1000
#5 ABCDEF600G400H       400
```